# Android Manifest and google play store permission issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions, manifest, android-permissions

I am using Android Native Plug-in for In-app and facebook posting in my Unity Game.

Initially I have published my game (version 1.0) with the default permissions comes with Android Native plug-in. However, I forget to remove **Read Contacts** permission. Now on updated version (i.e. 1.0.1) I have removed that permission from Manifest file.

When I install apk locally, game is not asking for a permission for read contacts. However in Google Play store under permissions Read Contacts permission is showing.

Can any one suggest me how can I remove this permission from play store as updated apk does not have permission. permission is on google play store it self.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Google doesn't update immediately the information about your apk. When did you publish the apk? Get it some time (like a day), if the permission is still there then you may have not remove it at all.

Comment: First apk is published before 1.5 month ago. and another apk with version 1.0.1 is published before 5 Days. Also permission is removed from Manifest file.